# Select value in dropdown based on db value in Ruby

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I have a simple Sinatra app that you can use to record the beers you drank on a certain night, their quantity, and type. To edit one of these user-entered nights I have a simple form that reflects the values that were entered when the drinking event was created:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= @beer.name %>" name="name"/>
<input type="text" value="<%= @beer.price %>" name="price"/>
```

So that's all well and good to have the value be populated from the database value. Now, how do I select the value for dropdown?

```
<select name="night">
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
  </select>
```

I found I could do it using inline jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".edit select[name=type] option").each(function(){
if ($(this).val() == "<%= @beer.type %>"){
  $(this).attr("selected", true );
}
});
$(".edit select[name=night] option").each(function(){
if ($(this).val() == "<%= @beer.night %>"){
  $(this).attr("selected", true );
}
});
});
</script>
```

But I don't really want to have to resort to inline js. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
<select name="night">
  <% ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"].each do |day| %>
    <option <%= 'selected="selected"' if day == @beer.night %> value="<%= day %>"><%= day %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with simple id selector for the select drop down box, like this:

```
<select id="day">...</select>

Then create an external javascript file, call it whatever you like such as day_select_handler.js  and include it in your view.

<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="day_select_handler.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

That way, the javascript file will be loaded when this page loads.
And it is not inline and can be re-used in other pages as well.

Comment: The javascript has ruby instance variables in it, so putting it in a js file doesn't work

Comment: I would say put the instance variables in your view using data-attributes.  And then in your javascript just retrieve the data-attributes using $('#something').data('beer_type')